# A feature that has different meanings in different ranges

Tags: machine-learning

In machine learning, how to deal with a feature like salary.  For example,  if I'm applying k-nearest neighbors by measuring the distance between data points based on features.  Let's say we have two points with salaries 2000 and 6000.  The difference between them is 4000. Let's view another two points with salaries 102000 and 106000. The difference here is still 4000$ but we humans consider the last two points closer or more similar than the first two points.

How do I incorporate such an intuition in machine learning?

Comment: Standardize and normalize my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of the following things (and many more):

- transform the feature using log function (thus 2000 and 6000 would be much further than 102000 and 106000)
- binarize feature into multiple buckets (you would create a feature for each range of salary and you are the one creating the buckets)
- change similarity function in k-nn to look at relative instead of absolute difference